# combineAll does not emit on empty array

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, reactive-extensions-js

[JSBIN Sample](http://jsbin.com/potiqa/edit?html,js,console)

I have a changeable set of child components (POJO object) that each have its own state stream. Each time a user triggers addChild/removeChild/clearChildren, a new set of children state streams is emitted with #switchMap. So far so good! (And so amazed by RxJS!)

With `Rx.Observable.from(arrayOfStateStreams).combineAll()` I get a good result as long as the `arrayOfStateStreams` isn't an empty array.

Since this is a partial state that is combined(Latest) on a higher level, I need to get an empty array emitted or the global state tree will contain old state data that is no longer true!

I can emit some reserved token like `['EMPTY-ARRAY-PLACEHOLDER-TOKEN']`, but that's just weird.
A better way would be to always append one last stream into the array so the last index can be considered trash. Still confusing code and state though.
Using `[null]` is not OK, since we could have a child state of `'null'`.

Anyone who can solve this in a good way? Can't this be supported since there should be no other representation of an empty array after #combineAll?

Comment: This has been solved in https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1910

Comment: Note: There was no change to RxJS as a result of this issue - the resolution was just to point out that you should manually check for an empty array (same code included in accepted answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Credits go to [github user trxcllnt who provided the following answer](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/1910#issuecomment-243617202):*

> combineAll won't emit unless the combined Observables emit at least
> one value, but you could check to ensure the collection you're
> combining is empty or not, and either combine or emit an empty Array:
>
> ```js
>  var arrayOfStreamsStream = Rx.Observable
>     .of(
>         [], [
>             Rx.Observable.of('blah-1'), // component state.
>             Rx.Observable.of('blah-2'),
>             Rx.Observable.of('blah-3')
>         ], [], [
>             Rx.Observable.of('foo-1'),
>             Rx.Observable.of('qux-2')
>         ]
>     )
>     .switchMap(function onMap(coll) {
>         return coll.length === 0 ?
>             Observable.of(coll) :
>             Observable.combineLatest(...coll);
>     })
>     .subscribe(function onSubscribe(data) {
>         console.log('onSubscribe START')
>         console.dir(data)
>         console.log('onSubscribe END')
>     })
> ```

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with `combineAll`. The problem is that `Observable.from` results in nothing (an empty observable) when passed an empty array.

The only viable solution that I can think of if you have to get a result from an empty array is to return something else in that case.

Ann example to illustrate the problem and a possible solution.

```
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

log('With data: ');
Rx.Observable.from(data)
    .subscribe(function (d) { log('data: ' + d); });

// Prints: 
// With data: 
// data: 1
// data: 2
// data: 3
// data: 4
// data: 5

var data = [];

log('Without data: ');
var nullDataObject = { msg: 'my null data object' };
Rx.Observable.from(data.length == 0 ? [nullDataObject] : data)
    .subscribe(function (d) { log('data: ' + d); });

// Prints: 
// With data: 
// data: [object Object]
```

Runnable example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7z51x7xb/).

When consuming this you simply filter away the object representing an empty array where appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!
It's very true that it was never going to work with an empty array as input. A better solution (and accepted answer) was to bypass the combineAll/combineLatest entirely with a ternary selector and just return an Observable.of([]) if the length === 0.

Answer (score 2):

Note: Similar issues exist with `combineLatest()` (the static version) which can be solved using `defaultIfEmpty()` - which works, but it screws up the typing of the output.

```
// array of Observables
const animals: Observable<{ species: 'dog' | 'cat' }>[] = [];  

// Type '{ species: "dog" | "cat"; }[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
combineLatest(animals).pipe(defaultIfEmpty([]));
```

In TypeScript you need to either know the type of the object or use `<any>[]` which means you then lose typing completely.

If you have a concrete type you can use one of these:

`defaultIfEmpty<Animal[]>([])`

`defaultIfEmpty([] as Animal[])`

I often don't have a concrete type for the return value of an observable. So I came up with an operator:

```
 export const emptyArrayIfEmpty = () => <T>(observable: Observable<T[]>) =>
                                        observable.pipe(defaultIfEmpty([] as T[]));
```

Then I can add the following and get out an empty array if `animals === []` without losing any typing information:

```
combineLatest(animals).pipe(emptyArrayIfEmpty());
```

Answer (score 1):

a possible workaround is to just pipe it with startWith();

```
combineLatest(potentiallyEmptyArray).pipe(
    startWith<any>([])
);
```

Comment: but then you get a glitch, https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/defaultIfEmpty is safer

Comment: _.=// i agree \\=._